# Kafka message corrupted in master but replica looks good

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**Kafka version** : 0.9

We have a java application trying to read from Kafka . but we see data corruption in kafka messages

**Below is the error from Java application :**

```
    org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Error deserializing key/value for partition varnish_raw_logs-31 at offset 568565
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException: Record is corrupt (stored crc = 1835858402, computed crc = 4025136930)
```

So i decided to see which node own the partition 31 and see how the data looks using the kafka dump log util . you see from below that parition 31 is owned by node-4 and node-2 has its replica .

```
Topic: varnish_raw_logs Partition: 31   Leader: 4       Replicas: 4,2   Isr: 4,2
```

Now when i use the dump util to see the logs from both node 4 and node 2 . I see that the data is valid in replica node(node-2) but corrupted in master .

[image: Left is corrupter master, Right is Replica]

**So my question is** : What is the root-cause for master(node-4) to get into this state ? While you can argue we should skip event specific errors . I don't want to miss these messages because i have a good message in replica .

Comment: 1) Maybe disc corruption on the leader? Can you provide any details about your disc setup and smart? 2) you could force a leader switch to read over it - just reverse the replica list (in ZK /brokers/topics/xx I think)

Comment: Late comment: If at least one replica is good, you can try to force a leader reassignment, then delete the corrupted file, and let it re-replicate